# How can I find the solution of this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given:
$$y^2 - 1 = (f(y) - 2xy)y' $$
$$y(1) = 4 $$
While:
$$ f(t) =  \begin{cases}
t, \space\space t\leq2\\
2, \space\space t\geq 2\\
\end{cases}
$$

How can I solve it?

---

I know that:
$(1-y^2)dx + (f(y) - 2xy)dy = 0 $.
And we can see that it's exact equation.

But how can I find the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write
$$
y^2-1=(\min(2,y)-2xy)y'.
$$
You could solve this on the smooth segments of the min function and then combine the parts.

Or you could apply a re-parametrization and solve for $x$ as function of $y$, which is linear
$$
(y^2-1)x'(y)+2yx(y)=\min(2,y),
$$
which should be easy to solve.

---

As you already found that the differential form is exact, you can directly integrate,
$$
d(x(y^2-1))=f(y)dy\implies x(y^2-1)=F(y)+C
$$
where $F$ is some anti-derivative of $f$,
$$
\int \min(2,y)\, dy=\int(2-(2-y)_+)\,dy =2y+\frac12(2-y)_+^2+C
$$

Then $x(y^2-1)=2y+\frac12(2-y)_+^2+7$ is the implicit form of the solution. One could now solve this for $y$, as it is a quadratic equation in both cases. Around the initial value, $(xy-1)^2=1+7x+x^2$, $y(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+7x+x^2}}x$.

Comment: I don't understand how can I solve it according to what that I writed in the question..

Comment: @Lutzl thats what I wanted to write the antiderivative F but I made some mistakes

Comment: In general, $d(uv)=vdu+udv$, so if you have an exact expression of this structure, then you can try to read off the factors $u,v$. Here it is easy to identify $x$ and $y^2-1$ as factors.

Comment: @Isham How can I solve it by find $ G(x,y) = x - y^2 x + h(y) $ so that $G_y = -2xy + h'(y) $ will be equal to $f(y) - 2xy$ ? NOTE: $G(x,y) = c$ is a solution to this problem..

Comment: @Isham: That's what I meant, you just would have to replace $f$ with $F$ in the second half of your computation, everything else was fine.

Comment: +1 yes ...Well anyway your answer is more complete it should be accepted as an answer..

Comment: @Software_t : That's correct, it leads directly to identify $h'(y)=f(y)$.

Comment: @LutzL And how can I find $h(y)$ like that ? It's be helpful if you will write $G(x,y)$ in this case (according to what that I writed).

Comment: @Software_t : You have to integrate a piecewise linear scalar function, it should be no obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2 - 1 = (f(y) - 2xy)y' \tag 1$$ 
FIRST PART : Solving without taking account of the boundary condition.

Case of $f(y)=2$ :
$$y^2 - 1 = (2 - 2xy)y' \tag 2$$ 
The change $u=xy-1 \quad;\quad y=\frac{u+1}{x}$ transforms the ODE into :
$$u^2 - 2xuu'+x^2-1=0$$
And with $v=u^2$ :
$$v-xv'+x^2-1=0$$
This is a linear ODE easy to solve : $v=x^2+1+c_1x$

$u=\pm\sqrt{x^2+1+c_1x}$
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(1\pm\sqrt{x^2+1+c_1x} \right) \tag 3$$

Case of $f(y)=y$ :
$$y^2 - 1 = (y - 2xy)y' \tag 4$$
$\frac{dx}{1-2x}=\frac{y}{y^2-1}dy$

This is a separable ODE easy to solve : 
$$y(x)=\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{c_2}{2x-1}} \tag 5$$

SECOND PART : Particular problem with conditions :
$$y(1) = 4 \quad\text{and}\quad f(t) =  \begin{cases}
t, \space\space t\leq2\\
2, \space\space t\geq 2\\
\end{cases}$$ 
The function $f$ is defined thanks to a dummy variable $t$ which must not be confused with the variable $x$ used in the ODE, that is the variable in the function $y(x)$. Thus the condition must be understood as :
$$ f(y) =  \begin{cases}
y, \space\space y\leq2\\
2, \space\space y\geq 2\\
\end{cases}$$ 
At $y(1)=4$ the condition specifies $f(y)=2$ and the ODE is Eq.$(2)$ above. The solution is $(3)$.

$y(1)=4=1\pm\sqrt{2+c_1}$ implies the sign plus and $c_1=7$

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x^2+1+7x} \right) \quad\text{in so far}\quad y\geq 2 \tag 6$$
Since $y'=-\frac{y^2-1}{2(xy-1)}$ with $xy-1>0$ then $y'<0$ thus $y(x)$ is decreasing from $y=4$ to $y=2$.

At $y=2=\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x^2+1+7x} \right)$, solving this equation gives $x=\frac{11}{3}$ .

At $y=2$ the condition specifies $f(y)=y$ and the ODE is Eq.$(4)$ which solution is $(5)$.

$y(\frac{11}{3})=2=\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{c_2}{2\frac{11}{3}-1}} $ implies the sign plus and $c_2=18$

$$y(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{18}{2x-1}} \quad\text{in so far}\quad y\leq 2  \tag 7$$
Obviously $y(x)$ is decreasing from $\left(x=\frac{11}{3};y=2\right)$ to $\left(x\to\infty , y\to 1\right)$.

[image]

Note : The curves above were drawn directly from the ODEs thanks to numerical calculus . They were not drawn from the equations of the above functions. If we draw the curves from the functions they cannot be distinguished from the preceding ones. This is a good checking of the theoretical calculus.